# Laravel: Add data to the Input::all()

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am grabbing the values from the parameters in the URL `domain.com?para=value` in the controller using
`Input:all()`

Is there a way to add more values to the `Input:all()` in the controller?

I have tried `$_POST['para'] = "value` and `$_GET['para'] = "value"` but no luck.

I've gone through the docs but cannot find anything.

Thanks

More Info

Here is what is returned

```
{
  "param_1" => "value",
  "param_2" => "value",
  "param_3" => "value",
}
```

I would like to add another param into the `Input:all()`

```
{
  "param_1" => "value",
  "param_2" => "value",
  "param_3" => "value",
  "NEW_PARAM" => "NEW VALUE",
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "add more values to Input::all() in the controller? "

Comment: I've updated the original question

Comment: `$input = Input::all(); $input['para'] = 'value';`

Comment: Tried that one but the only issue is the library I am using is taking the `Input::all()` value and I cannot pass in a variable.

Answer (score 19):

In laravel 5, you can use

```
Request::merge(['New Key' => 'New Value']);
```

or by using request() helper

```
request()->merge(['New Key' => 'New Value']);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should never need to add anything to Input. You should assign Input like so...

```
$arr = Input::all();
```

And then add to $arr like so...

```
$arr['whatever'] = 'whatever';
```

If you need to get that value in another part of the stack, try to pass it through yourself.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

**Best way to add data into the `input::all()` in laravel.**

> **Solution 1**

add ***Request package*** at the top of the page.

```
use Request;
```

Then add following code into your controller.

```
Request::merge(['new_key' => 'new_value']);
```

---

> **Solution 2**

You can assign all the `Input::all();` to a variable and then you can add new data to the variable. Like below.

```
$all_input = Input::all();

$all_input['new_key'] = 'new_value';
```

---

> **Add an input value on the fly inside a request instance**

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $request->request->add(['new_key' => 'new_value']);
}
```

---

> **Remove data from an input value on the fly inside a request instance**

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $request->request->remove('key');
}
```